# Can someone please explain this equality?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, analysis

[image]

It is part of the geometric proof of the theorem : Let $v_2 \in \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ be any time-like vector. Then $q_L(w,w) > 0$ for any nonzero vector w in
the $Lorentz$ complement $span\left< v\right>^{\perp}$; to put another way, any non-zero vector in $span\left< v\right>^{\perp}$
is space-like.

Answer (score 1):

It's plain algebra:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_iw_i\right)^2=
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_iw_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n v_jw_j\right)=
\sum_{i,j=1}^n v_iw_iv_jw_j
$$
and
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i^2\right)=
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n w_j^2\right)=
\sum_{i,j=1}^n v_i^2w_j^2.
$$
Moreover:
$$
(v_iw_j-v_jw_i)(v_iw_j-v_jw_i)=
v_i^2w_j^2-2v_iv_jw_iw_j+v_j^2w_i^2
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n(v_i^2w_j^2+v_j^2w_i^2)=
\sum_{i,j=1}^nv_i^2w_j^2+\sum_{i,j=1}^nv_j^2w_i^2=
2\sum_{i,j=1}^nv_i^2w_j^2.
$$
Note also that
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n
\quad\text{is a shorthand for}\quad
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n
$$